# excel vba compile error on year function

Tags: vba, function, excel, compiler-errors

I am writing a vba subroutine in excel vba that totals the quantity of lbs sold to customers for varying  years and for some reason I am getting a compile error with the year function. Could someone please explain why? Here's my code:

```
Private Sub lbsPerCustPerYear_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Cust As String
Dim Cust2 As String
Dim Total As Integer
Dim Output As Range
Dim Output2 As Range
Dim Year1 As Date

Total = 0
Year1 = Range("K6").Value
Cust = Range("C6").Value
Cust2 = Range("C7").Value
Set Output = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2)
Set Output2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 3)

For i = 1 To 14750
Year1 = Range("K5").Offset(i, 0).Value
If IsDate(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11)) Then
If Cust = Cust2 And Year(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11)) = 2012 Then
Total = Range("Q5").Offset(i, 0).Value + Range("Q6").Offset(i, 0).Value
Cust = Range("C5").Offset(i, 0).Value
Cust2 = Range("C6").Offset(i, 0).Value
Output.Value = Cust
Output2.Value = Total

Else
Cust = Range("C5").Offset(i, 0).Value
Cust2 = Range("C6").Offset(i, 0).Value
Year1 = Range("K5").Offset(i, 0).Value
Set Output = Output.Offset(1, 0)
Set Output2 = Output2.Offset(1, 0)

End If

Else
Cust = Range("C5").Offset(i, 0).Value
Cust2 = Range("C6").Offset(i, 0).Value
Year1 = Range("K5").Offset(i, 0).Value
Set Output = Output.Offset(1, 0)
Set Output2 = Output2.Offset(1, 0)

End If
Next i



End Sub
```

The error is in the line:

```
If Cust = Cust2 And Year(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11).Value) = 2012 Then
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this code is edited to fix the problem but I am now getting an overflow error on the line:  Total = Range("Q5").Offset(i, 0).Value + Range("Q6").Offset(i, 0).Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does each cell in column 11 contain a valid date or year?

You could check this first:

```
If isdate(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11).Value) then

  If Cust = Cust2 And Year(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11).Value) = 2012 Then

......

  end if

else

'handle invalid date

end if
```

Something else I've noticed is you've used Year as a variable name, change this to dtYear or something as this may conflict with the Year function in the object library.

Comment: so i did that, but now I'm getting an application-defined or object defined error

Comment: and I also changed year the variable to year1

Comment: What's the value of that cell when it fails?

Comment: Your loop also starts at 0, so that line is looking for Row 0. Try changing this to 1. (For i = 1 To 14750)

Comment: it doesn't say where it fails it just gives me the error and no because I'm only using the loop to offset the cells, so the starting offset is 0, but the starting cells are defined.

Comment: oh i see what your're saying you mean the row value in the if statement, ill fix that

Comment: I now get a type mismatch on that if statement line

Comment: i changed it to look like this:                                          If IsDate(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11)) And Cust = Cust2 And Year(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11)) = 2012 Then

Comment: You need to use the isdate function in a separate line before that If statement, in the way that i wrote in the original answer

Comment: when i do that it screws up the for loop

Comment: I'm going to edit the code above to look like my current code because I'm still getting a type mismatch on the if statement when i do the two separated if statements

Comment: You need to check what the value of i is when the code fails and then check the value of both of those cells  (Range("Q5").Offset(i, 0).Value + Range("Q6").Offset(i, 0).Value)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you have done is correct. Now you only need to check whether

1) `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11).Value` This particular cell is formatted as date.

2) Try using this instead `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11)`. Remove .value from the statement.

Comment: so i did what the guy above suggested but I am now getting an  application-defined or object defined error, do you know why that is happening?